# "same" values appear in the leaf in an ADD

Tags: cudd

In my ADD computation, I often have repeated values in the leaves. Should they be automatically compressed?

For example:

-0-0--  191.452

-0-1--  191.452

-1-0--  191.452

-1-1--  191.452

One guess is that they have different mantissa which is not shown. But I also have values with more mantissa:

---0-0  8.14148

---0-1  9.65706

---1-0  8.14148

---1-1  9.65706

I can only suppose the hidden digits are different so they appear in different leaves...

It seems like it only shows 6 digits. Can I change this setting?
Can anyone confirm my doubts? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the "epsilon" determining whether two values are considered equal.

This should set the epsilon value to a millionth:

```
Cudd_SetEpsilon(manager, 1.0e-6);
```

The default is defined in cuddInt.h as 1.0e-12:

```
#define DD_EPSILON  (1.0e-12)
```

If I am not mistaken, the printing happens in the internal function `ddPrintMintermAux` in `cuddUtil.c` using [`fprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) with the `%g` conversion specifier. You could change that code in CUDD and rebuild it to print the numbers with higher precision.